How do you perform an ice slide?
In Trackmania 2020 (maybe other games in the series as well), there is something called an ice slide. It's not explicitly told to you, but it's commonly mentioned by players of the game. It has something to do with angling your car a certain amount while with the icy tires condition, and maybe the brake key.
How do you perform an ice slide?

Here is how to do it:
Steer to the side until roughly 90 degree angle.

Then counter-steer fully to the opposite direction (e.g hold left when trying to go right). Your car will start accelerating and slowly return into a straight position.

You can control your slide angle in two ways:

by tapping the brake button to tighten your line
releasing gas to loosen your line or rotate your car back to straight faster

Images taken from this tutorial.
